# decompose object to this attributes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to decompose an object into attributes as follows;

```
let example = {name: 'Fred', age:20}
const {name, age} = example;
```

But, I would like it to do to the this.name, and this.age of the class it is in. Something like;

```
class Test = {

   name: ''
   age: null

   constructor(example) {

       {this.name, this.age} = example;

   }


}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: I tried a few different scenarios, without success.  Are you implying the above works, or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It **is** possible to assign value to objects using destructuring. It is definitely NOT recommended. You can see why:

```js
class Test {
  name = ''
  age = null
  constructor(example) {
    ({ name: this.name, age: this.age } = example) // <- dont't forget the parenthesis
  }
}

console.log(
  new Test({ name: 'name', age: 10 })
)
```

If the properties of `example` and the `class` are same, you can just use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
class Test {
  name = ''
  age = null
  constructor(example) {
    Object.assign(this, example)
  }
}

console.log(
  new Test({ name: 'name', age: 10 })
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the 2 scenarios, and the call out to the anti-pattern.